# What does "threshold" monitoring statistic mean in Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have an Amazon RDS Mysql database that I would like to resize from db.m3.large to db.t2.small in order to reduce costs.

Some relevant facts:

The db.m3.large has 2 vCPUs, 7.5 GiB memory and 500 Gig storage allocated.
The db.t2.small has 1 vCPU and 2 GiB memory.

Amazon's RDS Monitoring reveals the current RDS's CPU usage is a mere .75%. Its storage is 475K MB, a tiny fraction of the 500 Gig available.

The memory is where my question comes in. It's at 1040 MB, i.e. about 13% of available 7.5 GiB - not much but significantly higher relative to the other metrics. It's also showing to be right at the threshold for memory use on the amazon metrics display.

Question: why is 13% be close to any threshold? Where is this threshold determined?

Also, if I migrate to the db.t2.small instance, the memory usage would be at over 50%, right? Would this be really bad?

Comment: this should be helpful to you: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93184, specifically the 'show global variables' command.

Comment: Thanks. I had actually seen that, but it never hurts to double-check. I've reduced the size of our test servers and it's going to save $220 /month - wish it went to my paycheck!